# Refresh Token in Connected App (change password)

Tags: refresh-token

I have been trying to find any answers or documents in Salesforce about this.
I am using the Connected App and use the Refresh Token. Set the Refresh Token Policy: Refresh token is valid until revoked.

When I change the password of my salesforce account, does it affect the Refresh Token?
After 2 days since I change the password, the refresh token was expired or invalid.

Can someone provide me any reasons/causes that the Refresh token will expire?

Answer (score 5):

Changing your username, password, or security token (or even all of them) will not revoke a Refresh Token. A token expires when (a) the session is specifically revoked (e.g. in Setup > Session Management or Setup > Connected App OAuth Usage), (b) times out, as configured by the Connected App Refresh Token Policy, which may be set to either "until revoked", "immediately", "not used for X time", or "expires after X time", (c) intentionally logged out somehow, or (d) the same user logs in more than five times for the same Connected App, which automatically kills the oldest session to keep the limit at five active sessions. If you have a shared user account, or use multiple devices, you may have been subject to the five session limit. Otherwise, you'd need to look at the settings mentioned above to determine why your Refresh Token expired.